# How can I get only the ancestry processes of a given process?

Tags: process, pstree

Is it correct that

- `pstree <pid>` will output all the descendant processes of the given process
- `pstree -s <pid>` will output all the descendant processes and ancestry processes of the given process

How can I get only the ancestry processes of a given process?

Thanks.

Comment: similar: [View current user process ancestors and formating the output](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/250368)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always walk the ancestry tree by hand using `ps -o ppid=`:

```
#! /bin/bash -
pid=${1?Please give a pid}
while
  [ "$pid" -gt 0 ] &&
    read -r ppid name < <(ps -o ppid= -o comm= -p "$pid")
do
  printf '%s\n' "$pid $name"
  pid=$ppid
done
```

Or to avoid running `ps` several times:

```
#! /bin/sh -
pid=${1?Please give a pid}
ps -Ao pid= -o ppid= -o comm= |
  awk -v p="$pid" '
    {
      pid = $1; ppid[pid] = $2
      sub(/([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+){2}[[:space:]]*/, "")
      name[pid] = $0
    }
    END {
      while (p) {
        print p, name[p]
        p = ppid[p]
      }
    }'
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is there some reason to use `bash` in the shebang of one script, and `sh` in the other? (2) Is there some difference between double dash and single dash https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459208/signal-the-end-of-option-arguments-double-dashes-vs-single-dash

Comment: @Tim, for (1) that's because `<(...)` is not sh syntax. That will only work in `zsh`, `bash` or recent versions of `ksh93`. `... | read -r pid name` would only work in `zsh` or `ksh93`, here-doc+cmdsubst would be sh but more convoluted and less efficient. For (2), see [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729)

Comment: Thanks. (1) Can both scripts use `bash` in shebang?

Answer (score 2):

You can try following, I found it in [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pstree) :
-h
 This highlight the current process and its ancestors.
-n
This will sort processes with the same ancestor by PID instead of by name.